# Limit based on Count

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I use one table for categories and content.

Value of Categories in pid field is 0.

For example:

Example Table

```
--------------------------
id | pid | name
--------------------------
1  | 0   | Some catgory 1
--------------------------
2  | 1   | Some content of first category
--------------------------
3  | 1   | Other content of first cat
--------------------------
4  | 0   | Second category
--------------------------
5  | 0   | Category number 3
--------------------------
6  | 5   | Content of category 3
--------------------------
7  | 4   | Content of 2 cat
--------------------------
8  | 5   | Content of 3 cat
--------------------------
9  | 5   | Other Content of 3 cat
--------------------------
10 | 5   | One more content of 3 cat
--------------------------
11 | 4   | Content of 2 cat
--------------------------
12 | 5   | One more content of 3 cat
--------------------------
13 | 1   | First cat content
--------------------------
14 | 1   | Other content of 1 cat
```

How to get all categories and 10 content items in one query?

Comment: 10 content items per category? or in total

Comment: 10 content items and all categories.

Comment: like (SELECT * FROM table WHERE pid!=0 LIMIT 0,10)+(SELECT * FROM table WHERE pid=0) result will be 10 content items and all categories in table

Comment: total (10 content items and all categories)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the results of two separate queries in a single query use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT id, pid, name
FROM yourtable
WHERE pid = 0
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT id, pid, name
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE pid <> 0
    LIMIT 10
)
```